# "Method does not override any method from its superclass" Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

This code is swift 2

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let playerViewController = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController
    playerViewController.videoID = channelsDataArray[selectedVideoIndex]["videoID"] as! String   
}
```

Errors
 "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Please solution for swift 3

Comment: What class is this method inside? Is it not `UIViewController`?

Comment: Did you intend to override a method from your superclass? And what is your superclass? Does it have a similar method?

Answer (score 36):

In Swift 3 and later, it is [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) and the second parameter is `Any`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? PlayerViewController {
        destination.videoID = channelsDataArray[selectedVideoIndex]["videoID"] as! String
    }
}
```

In the future, if you temporarily comment out your method and start to type `prepare`, code completion will show you the proper method signature.

Comment: Same is true for Swift 4